# What's the most efficient way to search a set in c++

Tags: c++

For example to traverse a string and count the number of vowels I could use

```
  for (int i=0; (x=inputString[i])!='\0';i++)
    if (x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u') numVowels++;
```

In functional languages like haskell or erlang we can do lists:member(x,"aeiou")

In some object oriented languages I can do something like ["a","e","i","o","u"].find(x)

What's the cleanest way to do this in C++ without the x==.. || x==.. || ...

Comment: To be honest OP, looking at the answers people suggest below, I have to ask what is wrong with what you have?  Your code is very clear, it is clear what is meant, what the code does, and furthermore it is clear that there is no unnecessary overhead calling `std::` routines, etc.  I don't see a reason to change it.

Comment: @Andrey: Will it work with an empty string?

Comment: it will work with an empty string.in that case the for loop wont start as the condition violates in the first step

Comment: @James Yes, if you mean a string consisting of a single '\0'.  Are you asking if it will work with a null pointer?  Or with an uninitialized pointer? ...

Comment: @Andrey, rjv answered my question. I wasn't sure if there was an `inputString[0]` for an empty string (`""`)

Comment: @Andrey I don't think he is saying there is anything wrong with it, I think he is just asking if C++ has a feature similar to the other languages he mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inputString.find_first_of("aeiou");
```

This will give you the first index of any matching element. You can do this in loop to get all matching element:

```
size_t idx=0;
do{
    size_t current = inputString.find_first_of("aeiou",idx);
    idx = current;
}
while(current!=string::npos);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
for (auto c: inputString)
{
    c = std::tolower(c);
    if ((c == 'a') || ... (c == 'u'))
    {
        ++numVowels;
    }
}
```

Just because a language lets you write it in one line doesn't mean it's faster.

If you really, really wanted to get rid of the `==` you could do

```
#include <stdint.h>

//                    a  b  c  d  e  ....
const uint8_t TABLE[] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ... };

for (uint8_t c : inputString)
{
   if (std::isalpha(c))
   {
       numVowels += TABLE[std::tolower(c) - 'a'];
   }
}
```

Comment: He never explicitly stated whether he has a C string or a C++ string. Would this work with both?

Comment: @mebob Good point, don't think so. The guts of the agorithm would be the same though.

Comment: Yeah, true. Also, I like that look-up table idea: even though it uses up a lot more RAM (relatively), if you are searching through a very large string, then it will become very fast once (if) the table gets cached.

Comment: @mebob it should probably be `uint8_t` instead of `int`, then it's only 26 bytes.

Comment: Beware that the one-argument versions of both `std::tolower` and `std::isalpha` take an `int` parameter that is required to be positive or EOF. So on implementations where `char` is signed, and assuming `c` deduces as `char`, the code has undefined behavior in the event of characters with negative values. You can either use `tolower((unsigned char)c)` or the two-arg `tolower` from `<locale>`.

Comment: Also, the lookup table is very slightly dubious. The value of `'j' - 'a'` is 16 in EBCDIC and 9 in ASCII. Then again, if you're going to write code that isn't strictly portable, ASCII is one of the less restrictive assumptions you could make.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this:

```
#include <algorithm>

auto const numVowels = std::count_if(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(),
                       [](char c) { return c == 'a' || /* ... */ || c == 'u'; })
```

Comment: Sorry but I really think the code that the OP posted is way more readable and is probably faster as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that is the "best" way to do it. To make it cleaner, you might write a macro or function that just carries out that comparison, i.e. `bool CheckForVowel(char in)` or something like that. Then, you could just use that function: `if(CheckForVowel(x)){...}`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you could use `std::find()()`:

```
std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c) {
        static std::string const vowels("aeiou");
        return vowels.end() != std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), c);
    });
```

Sadly, the notation for algorithms doesn't support ranges [yet]. If it did, the operation could be written somewhat nicer as

```
ranges::count_if(str, [](char c){ return !ranges::find("aeiou"r, c).empty(); });
```

where `r` is a suitable user-defined literal producing an character sequence range.

Answer (score 1):

The title ("most efficient") doesn't seem to match the question ("cleanest").

Given that `["a","e","i","o","u"].find(x)` counts as "clean", I suppose that the closest C++ equivalent is `std::string("aeiou").find(x) != -1`.

I'd also clean up the loop. If you insist on a nul-terminated string for the input, then:

```
static const std::string lower_vowels("aeiou");
char x;
while ((x = *inputString++)) {
    numVowels += (lower_vowels.find(x) != -1);
}
```

If you change the input to `std::string` then:

```
for (char x : inputString) {
    numVowels += (lower_vowels.find(x) != -1);
}
```

It's *probably* not the most efficient, but that's another story. What you have is likely to be pretty close to optimal. I doubt you'll beat it without some fairly ugly code, because what you're basically saying is "can I do better than the compiler at optimizing these 5 comparisons against integral constants?"